# In UML if a class is inhereted from another do I need to show dependency, if I use the specialisation from the generalisation?

Tags: inheritance, uml

If I have a class A that extends B, and I use a temporary object of class A in one of the functions of B, then do I need any additional notation on an UML diagram between A and B beside the generalisation arrow? For example dependency from B to A ?

I know it's an utterly bad practice, and I would never use it in real code, but I need to know it for an assignment.

what I mean by code:

```
class B {
    public void foo() {
        A a = new A();
        a.foo();
    }
}

class A extends B {
   public void foo() {
       System.out.println("foo of A");
   }
}
```

Comment: Which UML diagram(s) do you mean? What is your guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Usage dependency from A to B in addition to your Generalization. 
A Generalization as a Usage implies a relationship between its source and its target but the meaning is different between both of them.